# Walking the circle in steps

Tags: geometry, circles

We're walking on a circular path by making a step forward and turning right a constant angle each time.

If we shorten our step n times, how should the angle change, such that circular path we're walking remains the same?

[image: Description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be the radius of circle, $L$ be the length of step, and $\alpha$ be measure of the correspondent central angle. You can easily see that $\alpha$ is the turning angle.

Note that $L = 2R \sin\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$.

Now, we want to reduce $L$ by $n$ times, $R$ remains unchanged.

Therefore,

$\dfrac{L}{n} = 2R \sin\dfrac{\beta}{2}$, where $\beta$ is a new turning angle.

So, we have $n \cdot \sin\dfrac{\beta}{2} = \sin\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$.

After all, $\beta = 2\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}}{n}\right)$.

Comment: I've drawn your last function on a graph with constant alpha with regard to n and it looks like that for angles < 90 degrees approximation beta = alpha / n seems surprisingly good (errors reach around 0.02 degrees). However, for bigger angles, values start differing more.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume the start and end points of each step lie on a fixed circle which has radius $R$. Then if each step has length $l$ and the angle turned between one step and the next is $\theta$, then $\theta$ is also the angle of the arc between the start and end points of each step. So

$l = 2 R \sin \left( \frac {\theta}{2} \right)$

If our step length changes to $l'$ then the angle turned between one step with length $l'$ and the next will now be

$\theta' = 2\sin^{-1} \left( \frac{l'}{2R} \right)$

At the point where we change our step length from $l$ to $l'$ then the angle between the last step with length $l$ and the first step with length $l'$ will be

$\frac{\theta + \theta'}{2}$

Answer (score -1):

Well i guess you would be walking in a regular cyclic polygon. So if the number of sides(steps) is n, the angle will be $\frac{n-2}{n}\cdot\theta$
You will be able to calculate the change yourself.

Comment: It depends on the angle, whether it is regular cyclic polygon, or more complicated path (take, for instance, 98 degrees - there is no number of sides to work with. If you take value like 90-sqrt(2) degrees, the figure won't even be closed)

Comment: Well if the angle is 98 degrees, you won't be able to make a complete circle. You need to travel along a regular polygon to complete the circle.

Comment: I don't have to return to the initial point - I'm still walking around a circle (on a circular path). I modified initial question a little.